# Is it possible to reference another script inside the main one

Tags: java, drjava

At school we use a program doctorjava for coding. Now is it possible to import a class with custom methods that is located in a whole other script and if it is how can you reference it?

edit: I know how to import java classes and packages and was just wondering if it's possible for self made scripts with classes and methods to be imported/referenced like the pre-made ones.

edit 2:
I use drJava to make and compile my scripts. The scripts are save as a .java file and the compiled file is saved as .class .
I have 2 scripts
Mathematics.java

```
public class Mathematics
{    
 public static int sum(int a, int b)
 {
   int result=a+b;
   return(result);
 }
}
```

and Test.java

```
public class Test
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   int x=12;
   int y=36;
   //here i want to use the sum method from the mathematics class
  }
}
```

I am new to programming and have only made these to scripts and put them into a folder named test on my desktop. Both scripts are compiled to their respective .class counterpart. What do i need to do now to make the sum method work in the test.java script. I can only use drjava, because this is what we use in school
Is what i want even possible and how to do it?

edit3: the problem was only in me forgetting about the main method in the test.java script. But what if the mathematics script isn't in the same folder
but inside a folder that is inside the test folder
`directory tree:
  test.java
  test.class
  methods
   Mathematics.java
   Mathematics.class`
in this case the mathematics script is in a subfolder called methods
what does it need to have changed in the script for it to work if possible?

Comment: https://www.leepoint.net/language/10basics/import.html

Comment: You can reference any Java code, it just has to be in the classpath.

Comment: so the same folder or something @SteveSmith

Comment: It needs to be in the correct folder based on its `package`, and the root of the package needs to be in the classpath.

Comment: @SteveSmith could you put a detailed explanation  with some code as the answer, because frankly i am getting confused. I am quite new to programming and English is not my 1st language so the terms you are using are unknown to me and confuse me.

Comment: It might be because your Mathematics sum method doesn't return a result, and your Test class doesn't have a method.  Do you get an error with your code, even before you've tried to add the sum method to the test class?

Comment: @SteveSmith Frankly the return was only forgot here and not in the actual script in the actual script there is the return method. And holy crap there is no main method in test.java. After i added the main method everything works and the calling of the method is normal. I would have never even noticed without you pointing it out

Comment: @SteveSmith sorry to bother you more i edited the post with a kind of a sub question what do i need to change in the code if it's in a sub folder

Answer (score 0):

If the scripts are in the same directory the answer is simple for this example it looks like this

```
Mathematics.sum(x,y);
```

If not you are required to create a package by adding this line of code to the top

```
package methods;
```

The package name should be the same as your folder name in which it is located
Then simply put this line of code to the top of the script with the main method in

```
import methods.Mathematics;
```

methods referring to the package name and Mathematics referring to the .java/.class filename

Be cautious since naming the package/script the same as an already existent one in java may lead to errors